# Debugging run is slow in Spyder 5.5.0

Tags: python, debugging, spyder

Im using Spyder 5.5.0 to code Python 3.12.1. On Windows 10.

I'm fairly new to Spyder coming from R-Studio.

In debugging runs the code is very slow.

I see references of 20 to 30 times slower for debug runs referenced for specific older versions of Spyder.

Not allowed to install other IDEs so I could not cross reference that. But I could get an older Spyder version installed.

Previous questions indicate that Spyder 5.4.3 had this issue, but not Spyder 5.2.2.

Should I go back all the way to 5.2.2 or is there perhaps a newer version without the issue? Or is there another workaround?